# Firebase Storage CORS error in Vue.js and Nuxt.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, cors, nuxt.js, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a .pdf stored on firebase-storage from my web application (Vue.js + Nuxt.js)

But got this error

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/************o/chats%2F96U5ERFOmHBGswQhDhaR%2Fdc8c9b64-6bdb-4cd0-b0a9-f59e18f10113?alt=media'
> from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What I have tried so far is to install [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/proxy) and configure it like this:

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
proxy: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/*************"],
modules:[
  '@nuxtjs/proxy',
]
```

But error is still there

Answer (score -1):

You need to do the changes on firebase.

Create a file `cors.json`

```json
[
  {
    "origin": [ "https://example.com" ],
    "method": [ "GET" ],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

And upload it via gsutil (Windows)

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your bucket>
```